# Geo location navigator is Not Working in the Iphone Ios devices But it is Working in other Android devices and WebBrowser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am using geolocation using java script API key that is Working properly in the android and browser. browser means google. but it is not Working in iphone devices all iphone devices. this is the Issue the scenario is I have a one address field user add a current location field. When user click the current location icon. that time the location lat and long will be detect and fill automatically on that  address field. this function is Working properly in the android and Web browser but not Working in the iphone devices How I resolve this. I give the permission grant and website permission on safari all I check and do correctly I debug it in on that safari browser to connect mac in develop console. the console Shows status pending. I give this one in my console  navigator.permissions.query({ name: "geolocation" }) and give the location setting Allow But I got this How I resolve this issue

I want to set  all the devices and browser that location field When I click the current location icon  fill correctly in android, browser. Must in Iphone because this issue happens only in iphone devices

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.